# Tooltips don't display for JLabels in a JPanel in a JTable cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable

The following shows `JTable` cells each containing a panel that in turn contains two labels. I've set tooltips on the `JLabel`s, but they don't show up. (And thanks to @MadProgrammer for the original stripped-down code to display a `JTable` and illustrate `setToolTipLocation()`.)

I override `getToolTipText()` for one label, and call `setToolTipText()` for another; if I set a breakpoint in the former one, it is called but no tooltip appears. So I tried overriding `setToolTipLocation()`, though I'm not sure what appropriate values are for it; I'm not sure what coordinate system it would use, figured 10,10 would leave it in range of most things.

It's not shown here, I've also tried creating the labels outside the `getTableCellRendererComponent()` call, and setting their dimensions, background colors, and tooltips within `getTableCellRendererComponent()`. That doesn't work either.

What else do I need to do to see those tooltips?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
    
    public class Test
    {
      Border labelBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black);
    
      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
        new Test();
      }
    
      public Test()
      {
        EventQueue.invokeLater
        (new Runnable()
          {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
              JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
              frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
              frame.add(new TestPane());
              frame.pack();
              frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
              frame.setVisible(true);
            }
          }
        );
      }
    
      public class TestPane extends JPanel
      {
        public TestPane()
        {
          setLayout(new BorderLayout());
          int rows = 4;
          int cols = 3;
          DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(0, cols);
          for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
          {
            Object[] data = new Object[cols];
            for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++)
            {
              data[col] = row + "x" + col;
            }
            model.addRow(data);
          }
    
          JTable table = new JTable(model);
//          table.setToolTipText("table text");     // this works, but would block tooltips from UI children
          table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new TestCellRenderer());
    
          add(new JScrollPane(table));
        }
    
        public class TestCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer
        {
          @Override
          public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
              int row, int column)
          {
            // create two labels, put them side-by-side in a panel, and return
            // the panel as the component being rendered.
            JLabel label1 = new JLabel("a Banana @" + value.toString())
            {
              @Override
              public String getToolTipText() 
              { 
                return "AA"; 
              }
              @Override public Point getToolTipLocation(MouseEvent mouseEvent) { return new Point(10,10); }
            };
            label1.setBorder(labelBorder);
            label1.setToolTipText("AA");            // this tooltip text does not show up.
    
            JLabel label2 = new JLabel("b Banana @" + value.toString());
            label2.setBorder(labelBorder);
            label2.setToolTipText("BB");            // this tooltip text does not show up.
            
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            BoxLayout layout = new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS);
            panel.setLayout(layout);
//            panel.setToolTipText("panel text");   //this works, but would block tooltips on the JLabels
            panel.add(label1);
            panel.add(label2);
            
            return panel;
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: *"The following shows JTable cells each containing a panel that in turn contains two labels."* Why not use two cells, one for each of the content of the two labels? See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: Because in that column, the labels are different widths in different columns. Each row represents, in this instance, a directory on a disk. Each label represents the amount of disk space occupied by files with one extension -- exe, txt, etc. So one directory has different extensions, and a different percentage of each extension, than other directories.

Comment: (1+) Much better [mre].

Comment: When I said different widths in different columns, I actually meant different widths in different rows.

Comment: @camickr One of the problems, of course, is that, if you don't have a clear conceptual model of the system you're dealing with, it's very difficult to know what's relevant and what isn't. I had made 2 other minimal examples, only to find out that they didn't exhibit the problem. So my original post came at it from the other end, stripping out things that were application-specific, hoping someone would have *their* conceptual model clear enough to see what the problem was. In fact, even though I have code that does what I want functionally, I still don't know what the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

> I override getToolTipText() for one label

How about trying to override the `JTable#getToolTipText(MouseEvent)` method instead of `JLabel`:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class Test2 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Test2();
  }

  public Test2() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.add(new TestPane());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
    });
  }
}

class TestPane extends JPanel {
  public TestPane() {
    super(new BorderLayout());
    int rows = 4;
    int cols = 3;
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(0, cols);
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
      Object[] data = new Object[cols];
      for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
        data[col] = row + "x" + col;
      }
      model.addRow(data);
    }

    JTable table = new JTable(model) {
      @Override public String getToolTipText(MouseEvent e) {
        Point pt = e.getPoint();
        int vrow = rowAtPoint(pt);
        int vcol = columnAtPoint(pt);
        TableCellRenderer tcr = getCellRenderer(vrow, vcol);
        Component c = prepareRenderer(tcr, vrow, vcol);
        if (c instanceof JPanel) {
          Rectangle r = getCellRect(vrow, vcol, true);
          c.setBounds(r);
          c.doLayout();
          pt.translate(-r.x, -r.y);
          Component l = SwingUtilities.getDeepestComponentAt(c, pt.x, pt.y);
          if (l instanceof JLabel) {
            return ((JLabel) l).getToolTipText();
          }
        }
        return super.getToolTipText(e);
      }
    };
    table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new TestCellRenderer());
    add(new JScrollPane(table));
  }
}

class TestCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
  @Override public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("a Banana @" + value.toString());
    label1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
    label1.setToolTipText("AA");

    JLabel label2 = new JLabel("b Banana @" + value.toString());
    label2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
    label2.setToolTipText("BB");

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    panel.add(label1);
    panel.add(label2);

    return panel;
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems to work; I'll certainly accept this if no one comes up with something that doesn't involve two `instanceof` operations. I do have a question. I tried `Component possiblePanel = SwingUtilities.getDeepestComponentAt(this, mouseEvent.getX(), mouseEvent.getY());`, but it gives me TestPane, not one of the JLabels. Why doesn't that give me the JLabel at the MouseEvent point?

Comment: The `this` argument of `SwingUtilities#getDeepestComponentAt(this, ...)` seems to be an instance of `TestPane`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I said... "... but it gives me TestPane, not one of the JLabels." I was wondering why `getDeepestComponent()` doesn't give me, you know, the deepest component.

Comment: (1+), I borrowed you "layout" code in my implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Had some old code lying around that allowed you to override the `getToolTipText(...)` method of the panel being used as the renderer.

Unfortunately it only seemed to work when the GridLayout was used as the layout manager of the panel.

Using the "layout" code provided by `aterai` I was able to get the code working for a FlowLayout as well. (didn't try other layout managers):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TableRendererPanelHelp
{
    static class MultiLabelRenderer implements TableCellRenderer
    {
        private JTable table;
        private int row;
        private int column;

        private JPanel panel;
        private JLabel red;
        private JLabel blue;

        public MultiLabelRenderer()
        {
            red = new JLabel();
            red.setForeground(Color.RED);
            blue = new JLabel();
            blue.setForeground(Color.BLUE);

            panel = new JPanel( new FlowLayout(0, 0, FlowLayout.LEFT) )
            {
                public String getToolTipText(MouseEvent e)
                {
                    String tooltip = null;

                    Rectangle r = table.getCellRect(row, column, true);
                    setBounds(r);
                    doLayout();

                    Component c = getComponentAt( e.getPoint() );

                    if (c instanceof JLabel)
                    {
                        JLabel label = (JLabel)c;
                        tooltip = label.getToolTipText();
                    }

                    return tooltip;
                }
            };

            panel.add(red);
            panel.add(blue);
        }

        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, final int row, final int column)
        {
            this.row = row;
            this.column= column;
            this.table = table;

            panel.setBackground( isSelected ? table.getSelectionBackground() : table.getBackground() );

            if (value == null || value.toString().isEmpty())
            {
                red.setText("");
                blue.setText("");
            }
            else
            {
                String text = value.toString();
                red.setText( text.substring(0, 3) );
                red.setToolTipText( red.getText() );
                blue.setText( text.substring(3) );
                blue.setToolTipText( blue.getText() );
            }

            return panel;
        }
    }

    public static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JTable table = new JTable(5, 3);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer( new MultiLabelRenderer());
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );

        table.setValueAt("abcde", 0, 0);
        table.setValueAt("123456789", 1, 0);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.add( scrollPane );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> createAndShowGUI() );
    }

}
```

A benefit of this approach is that all the logic is contained in the renderer class and you don't need to override the JTable.

Also, this approach tries to reuse the JPanel and JLabels so you don't continually create new components every time a cell is rendered.

Comment: so it depends on the LayoutManager used? Interesting...

Comment: Just tried using a BoxLayout and the results are inconsistent. In my example the width of the second label on the second row is greater than the width of the label on the first row. When I move the mouse from an empty space on the first straight down to the text on the second row the tooltip is not being displayed. For some reason the "width" of the component is not being updated so the getComponentAt(...) method isn't finding the second label. However, when I use the FlowLayout it works fine. In the other answers the components are always a fixed size so you might not notice this problem.

Comment: well, in the use I want to make of it, the components are going to change size any time the overall window is resized. I got interrupted and haven't been able to try all these, but I need something like BoxLayout or your RelativeLayout; I *guess* FlowLayout might be ok, since I'm controlling the component widths and keeping their total to the width of the column, but I hate to use it like that -- seems like I'm using the wrong tool.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe late, but here a similar approach, should not depend on the layout manager.

All code is in the CellRenderer that directly extends JPanel, then it rethrows the getToolTip request to the subcomponent adapting the MouseEvent.

```
package test;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

public class TestTooltipTable {

    Border labelBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestTooltipTable();
    }

    public TestTooltipTable() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {
        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            int rows = 4;
            int cols = 3;
            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(0, cols);
            for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
                Object[] data = new Object[cols];
                for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
                    data[col] = row + "x" + col;
                }
                model.addRow(data);
            }

            JTable table = new JTable(model);
//          table.setToolTipText("table text");     // this works, but would block tooltips from UI children
            table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new TestCellRenderer());

            add(new JScrollPane(table));
        }

        public class TestCellRenderer extends JPanel implements TableCellRenderer {
            protected JLabel label1;
            protected JLabel label2;
            
            protected Rectangle cellRect;

            public TestCellRenderer() {
                setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
                label1 = new JLabel(" ");
                label2 = new JLabel(" ");

                label1.setBorder(labelBorder);
                label1.setToolTipText("AA"); // this tooltip text does not show up.

                label2.setBorder(labelBorder);
                label2.setToolTipText("BB"); // this tooltip text does not show up.

                add(label1);
                add(label2);

            }

            @Override
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
                    boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
                // create two labels, put them side-by-side in a panel, and return
                // the panel as the component being rendered.
                label1.setText("a Banana @" + value.toString());
                label1.setToolTipText("AA "+row+"x"+column);

                label2.setText("b Banana @" + value.toString());
                label2.setToolTipText("BB "+row+"x"+column); // this tooltip text does not show up.

                cellRect=table.getCellRect(row, column, true);
                
                return this;
            }

            @Override
            public String getToolTipText(MouseEvent event) {
                if (cellRect==null) {
                    return null;
                }
                
                setBounds(cellRect);
                doLayout();
                Point p=event.getPoint();
                Component c=SwingUtilities.getDeepestComponentAt(this, p.x, p.y);

                if (!(c instanceof JComponent)) {
                    return null;
                }
                p=SwingUtilities.convertPoint(this, p, c);
                MouseEvent newEvent = new MouseEvent(c, event.getID(),
                        event.getWhen(), event.getModifiersEx(),
                        p.x, p.y,
                        event.getXOnScreen(),
                        event.getYOnScreen(),
                        event.getClickCount(),
                        event.isPopupTrigger(),
                        MouseEvent.NOBUTTON);

                return ((JComponent) c).getToolTipText(newEvent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```